# Time complexity of insertion sort on k-shifted array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

This problem was asked in my algorithm course homework.

> You have an *n* sized, sorted array at first. Lets say `n=10` and the array is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. Then it is circularly shifted to the right by *k*. Lets say `k=3`. Now the array is `[8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.
>
> What is the time complexity if you apply insertion sort on this array, depending on *n* and *k*?

I researched this question a lot, but couldn't find a solution on the internet. How to determine the time complexity of insertion sort on such shifted array?

Comment: Did you just ask a question and immediately answered it yourself?
Are you testing Cunningham's Law or something?

Comment: @GeertPt Asking and self-answering questions is perfectly fine and allowed.

Comment: @GeertPt techniquely I didn't ask a question, shared a solution

Comment: @Baran OK, fair enough!

Comment: But a question on Stack Overflow should still be phrased as a question, not as a blog.

Comment: @trincot I've searched a way to solve this problem on stackoverflow but I couldn't before. So what is your problem if I put answer here that I've searched before?

Comment: I don't have a problem with the answer at all. My comment is about the post above which should be phrased as a question. Shouldn't be difficult to rephrase it.

Comment: Never mind, I updated the post for you. Have a look.

Comment: The number of swaps in insertion sort is the total number of pairs in the array in the wrong order. That's k(n-k) for a k-shifted array.

Comment: I remember answering or commenting on this same question a few days ago, which included some strong similarity to your answer (including testing it on arrays of size 2^16), but now it seems like that question has been deleted. Was the original question yours @Baran?

Comment: @PaulHankin yes it was

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the insertion sort:

```java
static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int key = array[i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && array[j] > key) {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j--;           
        }

        array[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

The time complexity mostly depends on the following lines because that's where comparing and swapping operations are done.

```java
while (j >= 0 && array[j] > key) {
    array[j + 1] = array[j];
    j--;
}
```

Take a paper, draw a swap table for each j value.

[image]

Eventually, you will understand that the algorithm gets into while loop `(n-k)` times, and whenever it gets in, it does swap operation `k` times. So, time complexity is `(n-k)*k`.

Lets prove it.

Put a swap counter variable to the algorithm.

```java
static int insertionSort(int[] array) {
    int swapCount = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int key = array[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && array[j] > key) {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j--;
            swapCount++;
        }

        array[j + 1] = key;
    }

    return swapCount;
}
```

Now, lets try it on our array described in the question.

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] baseArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        int n = baseArray.length;
        int k = 3;

        // Shift base array by k
        int[] shiftedArray = shiftArray(baseArray, k);

        // Calculate how many swaps done by the insertion sort
        int swapCount = InsertionSort.insertionSort(shiftedArray);

        // Theroitical value is calculated by using the formula (n-k)*k
        int timeComplexityTheoritical = (n - k) * k;

        System.out.print("Theoritical Time Complexity based on formula: " + timeComplexityTheoritical);

        System.out.print(" - Swap Count: " + swapCount);

        System.out.print(" - Is formula correct:" + (timeComplexityTheoritical == swapCount) + "\n");
    }

    // Shift array to the right circularly by k positions
    static int[] shiftArray(int[] array, int k) {
        int[] resultArray = array.clone();

        int temp, previous;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            previous = resultArray[array.length - 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < resultArray.length; j++) {
                temp = resultArray[j];
                resultArray[j] = previous;
                previous = temp;
            }
        }

        return resultArray;
    }

    static class InsertionSort {

        static int insertionSort(int[] array) {
            int swapCount = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                int key = array[i];
                int j = i - 1;
                while (j >= 0 && array[j] > key) {
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    j--;
                    swapCount++;
                }

                array[j + 1] = key;
            }

            return swapCount;
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

> Theoritical Time Complexity based on formula: 21 - Swap Count: 21 - Is
> formula correct:true

I've tried on array sized 2^16 and shifted it 2^16-1 times, each time the formula was correct.

The time complexity we found is not an upper bound or lower bound, it is the exact tight bound for this case. Therefore it is Theta. `Θ((n-k)k)`.

Comment: When  one talks about complexity, usually O/Ω/Θ notation is used. Here **Θ(n*k)**